# php: how to call an object and its methods with name as variable

Tags: php, oop, reflection

I need to make a universal caller for addons to my php project. I need to call models based on form field (POST):

```
    $moduleName = new ReflectionClass($module);
    $data = $moduleName->method($params);
    print_r($data);
```

This also doesn't work:

```
    $data = call_user_func_array($moduleName.'::method',array($params));
    print_r($data);
```

Why?

Is this right? I get ReflectionClass:method() 'not found or invalid function name' error.

How to call a new instance of the class by name from variable and function name also as variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
$className  = 'YourClassName';
$methodName = 'classMethodName';
$module     = new $className();                // create new class instance
$data       = $module->{$methodName}($params); // call your method
```

if `$params` is an array, and you want to pass it to your method as multiple arguments:

```
$data = call_user_func_array(array($module, $methodName), $params);
```

Since you tagged this [reflection](/questions/tagged/reflection), here's the other way:

```
$module    = new $className();
$reflector = new ReflectionMethod($module, $methodName);
$reflector->invokeArgs($module, $params);  // call_user_func_array() equivalent
```

Obviously you don't need to instantiate your class if the method you're trying to call is static.